# How get correct path default image using gem dragonfly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dragonfly-gem

I use for loading files gem dragonfly

I have model Photo:

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
    dragonfly_accessor :avatar do
      default  'public/avatar.png'    
    end
................................
end
```

When i call `pry(#<#<Class:0x007f83508fb8f0>>)> @photo.avatar.url`

I get

```
=> "/media/W1siZmYiLCJwdWJsaWMvYXZhdGFyLnBuZyJdXQ/avatar.png?sha=338938a0ea07d56b"
```

Setting file dragonfly.

**dragonfly.rb**

```
require 'dragonfly'

# Configure
Dragonfly.app.configure do
  plugin :imagemagick

  secret "7c510e8ed95f9929f09981ef5f42ffc75034703184575044d2835ebbbd2a350b"

  url_format "/media/:job/:name"

  datastore :file,
    root_path: Rails.root.join('public/system/dragonfly', Rails.env),
    server_root: Rails.root.join('public')
end

# Logger
Dragonfly.logger = Rails.logger

# Mount as middleware
Rails.application.middleware.use Dragonfly::Middleware

# Add model functionality
if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
  ActiveRecord::Base.extend Dragonfly::Model
  ActiveRecord::Base.extend Dragonfly::Model::Validations
end
```

I need path image for paste in image_tag. How can I get correct path **.../public/avatar.png**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I founded solution:

```
dragonfly_accessor :avatar do
      default  Rails.root.join('public', 'images', 'default', 'avatar.png')    
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **remote_url** instread of **url** to get full path
like

```
 @photo.avatar.remote_url
```

If you want to use the uploaded image in image tag, then you can directly use

```
image_tag(@photo.avatar.url)
```

Comment: Can you please write setting in dragonfly.rb file ? But what is the need of actual path because  @photo.avatar.url will set the image correctly

Comment: But you can use above path like image_tag(@photo.avatar.url) directly

Comment: when open direct url  http://localhost/media/W1siZmYiLCJwdWJsaWMvYXZhdGFyLnBuZyJdXQ/avatar.png?sha=338938a0ea07d56b, display error - DRAGONFLY: fetch file /home/ubuntu/workspace/public/avatar.png disallowed - use fetch_file_whitelist to allow it

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
img = Dragonfly[:images].fetch_file(File.join(Rails.root, 'public', 'toekomst', 'images', 'sample.png'))
```

refer this link (http://markevans.github.io/dragonfly/rails/)

Comment: How me add my path public/avatar.png?

Comment: Just add your image to this path `assests/images`

Comment: I added img = Dragonfly.app(:images).fetch_file(File.join(Rails.root, 'public', 'toekomst', 'images', 'avatar.png'))
    dragonfly_accessor :avatar do
      default img
      #'public/avatar.png'    
    end                                    Dont display: http://prntscr.com/aorxog. Image in assets/images