# Render Dragonfly images in PDF using wicked-pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf, dragonfly-gem

I am trying to render a pdf of my model containing images stored with dragonfly using wkhtmltopdf but I can't get it to work. The html page renders fine when I use the debug option for wkhtmltopdf but the pdf itself just gets an empty box where the image should go.
So far I've only found two sites where this is brought up ([a german blog](https://benjaminknofe.com/blog/2011/01/27/pdf-generieren-mit-rails-3-dragonfly-und-wicked_pdf/) and [a google forum thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dragonfly-users/yGAgB8PkN1M)), but neither solution solved it for me.
My suspicion is that I should use absolute paths to the image files, which is suggested in the [blog](https://benjaminknofe.com/blog/2011/01/27/pdf-generieren-mit-rails-3-dragonfly-und-wicked_pdf/), but when I try that solution the server gets stuck at:

```
Rendered images/show.pdf.erb (19.9ms) 
"***************[\"/home/oskar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/wkhtmltopdf\",
\"-q\", \"--encoding\", \"utf8\", \"--orientation\", \"Landscape\", 
\"file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20161007-8095-1nlruhe.html\", \"/tmp
/wicked_pdf_generated_file20161007-8095-1f6vr27.pdf\"]***************"
```

My code looks like this:

image.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  dragonfly_accessor :image
end
```

images_controller.rb:

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      render pdf: 'name',
             background: true,
             encoding: 'utf8',
             orientation: 'Landscape',
             :show_as_html => params[:debug].present?
    end
  end
end
```

show.pdf.erb:

```
<% if params[:debug].present? %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'document' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'pdf' %>
<% else %>
  <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'document' %>
  <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'pdf' %>
<% end %>

...

<%= image_tag image.url if image.image_stored? %>

...
```

image.url = `http://localhost:3000/media/W1siZiIsIjYyIl1d/imagename.png`

Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Please show `image.url`'s value. Are you sure it's a obsolute path ?  Which OS you have in your server side, Linux or Windows?

Comment: It's running on heroku in production and linux locally. And no, the URL is not absolute, I think that's one of the issues, but I havn't found a way of making it absolute and still render.

Comment: You may try: `<%= image_tag "#{Rails.root.to_s}/media/W1siZiIsIjYyIl1d/imagename.png" if image_stored? %>`

Comment: That didn't work, not locally nor in production

Comment: I saw that maybe hlepful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36442304/how-get-correct-path-default-image-using-gem-dragonfly/36442523

Comment: I saw that one too, and tried it. But it makes no difference from what I have right now.

Answer (score 1):

I know, my solution is ugly. But it works :)

```
def self.export_to(path)
  all.each do |image_model|
    image_model.image.to_file(Rails.root.join("tmp","image", image.id.to_s))
  end
end
```

And now I render images like this:

```
<img src="<%=Rails.root.join("tmp","image", image.id.to_s)%>" alt=<%= image.name %> >
```

Now you even could attach an `after_destroy` callback to remove the images.

Comment: I agree with the ugliness, but I will try this as a last resort! Will keep looking for better solutions a while longer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use: `image_tag(logo.path)`

Note the usage of `image_tag` and `path` instead of `wicked_pdf_image_tag` and `url`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `image_tag` with `wicked_pdf_image_tag`

```
<%= wicked_pdf_image_tag image.url if image.image_stored? %>
```

Comment: I've tried that, it still doesn't load. The wicked_pdf_image_tag just prepends the absolute path to the assets folder. Since the image I want to show is part of a model and not a static asset, it is not located there.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me use path

`<img src="<%=Rails.root.join(image.path)%>"  >`

in case the image object is a child

`<img src="<%=Rails.root.join(parentObject.image.path)%>"  >`

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and spent untold hours trying to figure it out.  As with everything Rails, once you know the answer it is *really easy*....  All I had to do was add the dragonfly directory to the Rails asset path in the appropriate environment file.

```
  config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/public/system/dragonfly"
```

I was then able to render the image using the wicked_pdf_asset_base64 helper method.

```
= image_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64(@product.main_image.path), width: 280, height: 200
```